# Compare two columns of a file using python or unix

Tags: python, shell

I have data in a file like csv, or a txt file with a specific seperator. for example:

```
date|Symbol
2017-05-01|A
2017-05-01|B
2017-05-01|C
2017-05-01|A
2017-05-02|A
2017-05-02|B
2017-05-02|C
2017-05-03|A
2017-05-04|A
2017-05-04|B
2017-05-04|C
2017-05-05|A
2017-05-05|A
2017-05-05|B
2017-05-06|C
2017-05-06|A
2017-05-07|A
2017-05-05|B
2017-05-07|C
2017-05-08|A
```

Now I want to check if any symbol is getting repeated on a particular day,and if yes, then the symbol with date. Like Symbol A is getting repeat on 01-May, B is on 05-May.

I am trying to do it by using python, that Putting all Symbols in a list, and then check it over column one if any date is getting repeated.

Is there any other solutions than this.

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line then split by pipe |:

```
ln.split("|")[1]
```

This will show characters like A B ...

Compare this with others

Comment: @lsaBoston, it will work, not efficient in case of large data (as i have)

Comment: You can make it dict format {dates1:"char",date2:"char", ...} then compare values. for key, values in data.items(): ...

Comment: seems helpful, but i extended this to creating a list of dictionaries, and dictionaries having key as date and value as a list of column 2. thanks

Comment: Make like this:     date1:["char1", "char2", ...]

Comment: yes like this, [{date1:["char1", "char2", ...]}, {date2:["char1", "char2", ...]}....]

Answer (score 0):

With python difflib https://pymotw.com/2/difflib/

```
import difflib
from difflib_data import *

d = difflib.Differ()
diff = d.compare(text1_lines, text2_lines)
print '\n'.join(diff)
```

Comment: it seems something new to me, but may be not useful here.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a list of dictionaries and each dictionary have key as data and list of column 2 as a value. now i checked in every dictionary if any thing is repeating.

If any one have better solution than this, then it is most welcome.

Updating implementation code for above:

```
with open(file_path,"rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=delmtr)
    for line in reader:
        if is_header == 1:
            is_header = 0
            continue
        date_dict = {}
        inst_fl_col = inst_col - 1
        date_fl_col = date_col - 1
        if line[date_fl_col] not in date_list:
            date_list.append(line[date_fl_col])
            instrument_list = []
            instrument_list.append(line[inst_fl_col])
            date_dict[line[date_fl_col]] = instrument_list
            p_list.append(date_dict)
            csvwriter.writerow(line)
            del date_dict,instrument_list
        else:
            for dicts in p_list:
                for k,v in dicts.items():
                    if k == line[date_fl_col]:
                        if line[inst_fl_col] not in v:
                            v.append(line[inst_fl_col])
                            csvwriter.writerow(line)
                        else:
                            count += 1
nw_fl.close()
print str(count)+" rows ignored in newly created "+new_file_name+" file"
del date_list[:],is_header,csvwriter,count
```

I did it by using basic knowledge of python, now i'm improving this using collections module and defaultdict class. Please let me know if any one require the improved code.

Suggestion are most welcome.